# Deck of 52 cards, 3 card rank/order repeat pattern probability.

Tags: probability, card-games

A standard deck of 52 playing cards is well shuffled and drawn 1 card at a time without replacement.  What is the probability that the ranks of the 3 most recently drawn cards (starting at drawn card 6) have already been seen in the exact same order in the already drawn cards?  For example, when the 6th card is drawn, we need to check if cards 4, 5, and 6 are the same exact ranks as cards 1, 2, and 3 in the same exact order.  If not, then we draw card 7 and check if cards 5, 6, and 7 have been seen in that same order in cards 1, 2, 3 or 2, 3,and 4...  So basically we are checking the last 3 cards drawn against all previously drawn triples, including overlapping triples (such as cards 2,3,4 that overlap cards 1,2,3)

So for example, using A, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, T, J, Q, K as the 13 possible card ranks, the following partial deck would be a pattern found scenario:

5, Q, 7, 3, K, K, 8, Q, 7, 3 because the Q, 7, 3 triple was previously seen in that exact order.

$UPDATE$: For clarification, you need not scan into the last 3 cards drawn for a match.  When I said overlapping triples I did not mean into the last 3 cards drawn, but rather overlapping triples such as scanning cards 1,2,3  then 2,3,4, then 3,4,5... from the last 3 cards drawn (start scanning after card 6 is drawn and after every other drawn card after that such as 7, 8,... 51, 52).

So my question is what is the probability this will happen at least once in a well shuffled deck?  That is, at least one triple pattern of ranks will repeat exactly in order in the same deck as the cards are drawn one at a time, as described above.

Comment: Is this question not possible to solve using mathematics or is it just very difficult?  I am not sure how to set this up mathematically but I did try some decks manually and I got 4 decks out of 20 that had this repeat property so it appears it is close to 20% but I am not sure how accurate that is cuz it was only 20 decks.  The average card position where this happened was 34 but again, I don't think 20 decks is enough to call that accurate.  Maybe this can be solved by computing the probability of no repeat exact triple and then taking the complement?

Comment: I think it is a very tedious question to get an exact answer for.  There are many cases and sorting them out is a lot of work.  It would be easy to program a statistical trial to do millions of cases.  Some people have code that would make writing that easy, but not me.

Comment: I ran a simulation of 100 million decks and the maximum # of overlapping triple sequences that were previously seen in the deck was only 7.  Therefore, a mathematical solution that considers this should be close enough to the correct answer to be acceptable.  Any deck with more than 7 overlapping triple sequences is so rare that we can basically ignore them.

Comment: If the first four cards are 2's, have "the ranks of 3 adjacent cards have already been seen"?  (Because 222 appeared twice?)

Comment: @irchans, no I am not counting adjacent quads as overlapping matching triples.  This visually and conceptually complicates things some.  My code simply checks the last 3 cards drawn (starting from the 6th card) with all previous 3 adjacent card triples (but not extending into the last 3 cards drawn).  I am not sure mathematically if that makes it easier or harder to compute.  It seems you can ignore adjacent quads cuz they do not count as a matching triple cuz the triple we are trying to match canNOT match part of itself, it MUST be previously seen in the drawn cards,

Comment: Also @irchans, I mentioned in the original question and in at least one comment that 6 cards is the minimum for a match to occur, which implies that if we call the last 3 cards dealt B and the cards dealt previous to those 3 cards A, we are checking for the appearance of B in A but not checking for the appearance of B in A+any part of B. As I stated previously, this is visually and conceptually simpler (such as when you use a real deck of cards to try it), plus it is slightly simpler to code which tends to speed up execution of the simulation which I now have at about 30 million decks an hour.

Comment: I am running a Monte Carlo type simulation of 1 billion 1 decks so I should have an answer Sunday morning (in about 24 more hours).  While it is running, I am investigating fast shuffle code for future similar simulations.  That is where most of the time is being spent.  Perhaps if I just generate 1 billion shuffled decks and save them to a disk file, I can reuse those in the future.  I could even bitpack them 2 cards per byte since there are only 13 possible ranks and 13*13=169 < 256. So it would be 26 bytes per deck.  26GB for 1 billion decks or slightly over 24GB if I fully bitpack them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any 3 card sequence can be:
No pair, one pair, 3 of a kind.

With probabilities $\frac{52\cdot48\cdot 44}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50}, \frac{52\cdot3\cdot 48\cdot 3}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50}, \frac{52\cdot3\cdot 2}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50}$ respectively.

Verify that these sum up to 1.

If the sequence is no pair.  There is a probability that a given 3 card sequence in the deck matches rank for rank is:

$\frac {3\cdot 3\cdot 3}{49\cdot 48\cdot 47}$

If a sequence has one pair, it is less likely.

$\frac {2\cdot 1\cdot 3}{49\cdot 48\cdot 47}$

If a sequence is 3 of a kind, it is impossible to have a second sequence that matches the first.

That two sequences of 3 cards match

$\frac {52\cdot 48\cdot 44\cdot 27+52\cdot 3\cdot 48\cdot 3\cdot 6}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48\cdot 47}$

How many non-overlapping pairs sequences of 3 cards are there in a 52 card deck? ${48\choose 2}$

How to explain this?  If we think of the first sequence of sequence $A$ and the second sequence as sequence $B.$

We can burn some amount of cards before the beginning sequence $A$, and some amount of cards after the end of sequence $B$ lets call these $a,b$ respectively.   The sum of the cards burnt must be less than  or equal to 46.

The number of pairs of non-negative integers such that $a + b \le 46$ is ${48\choose 2}$

(remember $a,b$ could equal $0.$)

$\frac {52\cdot 48\cdot 44\cdot 27+52\cdot 3\cdot 48\cdot 3\cdot 6}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48\cdot 47}\cdot {48\choose 2} \approx 23.8\%$

Update....

As has been pointed out by the original poster, I have the expected number of duplicated sequences...

Inclusion-Exclusion

Taking a shortcut....

$p = \frac {52\cdot 48\cdot 44\cdot 27+52\cdot 3\cdot 48\cdot 3\cdot 6}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48\cdot 47}$

$p{48\choose 2} - p^2{48\choose 2}{42\choose 2} + p^3{48\choose 2}{42\choose 2}{43\choose 2} \approx 20.34\%$ which is $0.2034$.

Comment: I wrote a simulation program to check this, scanning 10 million decks in about 1 hour of computer runtime, and I got 20.32%.  That same simulation program is telling me that on average, the first match (for those decks that have at least 1 match), is happening at drawn card # 36 (out of 52) so it takes a little more than 2/3rds of the deck to complete the match on average, but it can be interpreted as a little less (33 cards) since the first 3 cards are required before a match is even possible.  6 cards drawn is the minimum to create a match.  52 is the maximum for a match.

Comment: Then either my calculation is wrong, or your code of the simulation is wrong.  But, I am not interested in reviewing your code.  If you can find an error in my calculation, the please let me know.

Comment: My code is extremely short (24 lines) and simple so I highly doubt there is an error in it.  It just scans all triples starting at cards 4,5,6 then progresses thru cards 5,6,7 then 6,7,8... all the way up to 50, 51, 52, always checking the previously seen cards for the same triple in the same exact order.  I strongly suspect the correct answer is close to 20.32%, not 23.8%.  That is a fairly large discrepancy.  I will set a bounty on this so people are more motivated to solve it cuz I want to know where the error is and confirm what the correct answer is.

Comment: Doug M., I think I found the error in your computation.  You are overcounting the scenarios where there are multiple matching triples in the same deck.  I clearly stated in the question what is the probability of at    least one triple matching in the deck, meaning that if there is only 1 match or multiple, it doesn't matter, as long as there is at least one.  I confirmed this by changing my simulation program to count up the cases where a single deck also has more than 1 match and the % then went up to about 23.8%, matching yours.  So as the question was asked, 20.32% is the correct answer.

Comment: Doug M., if you can fix your calculations to exclude the overcounting, I will go ahead and give you the checkmark for best answer.  You have to not double count something like 2 4 6 8 2 4 6 Q K 2 4 6 ...  That counts as 1 matching deck, not 2.  So for example, if this was your first deck results and the 2nd deck had 0 matches, then the "observed probability" would be 50%, not 66.7%.  I am not sure what the maximum # of matches per deck can be but I can run a simulation to get an idea.  I am thinking computationally it might be a "bear" to subtract these out, however with code it is 1 keyword.

Comment: Doug M, is this the final complete answer or is there a -$p^4$ term, +$p^5$ term ...?  How many more terms are there?  Our answers are virtually identical now.

Comment: As $p$ increases in power, each successive term declines in significance.

Comment: Doug,  when you applied Inclusion-Exclusion you made an independence assumption.  Let A be the event that the first three cards have the same rank sequence as cards 4,5, and 6.   Let B be the event that cards 8, 9, and 10 have the same rank sequence as cards 14,15, and 16.   Obviously, P(A)=P(B).  But how do you know that P(B|A) = P(B)  (i.e. how do you know A is independent of B) ?

Comment: @David: It sounds like your code, if it starts at cards $(4,5,6)$, will not catch all the cases where two identical triples overlap.  For example, if the first four cards are all kings, then the triples at $(1,2,3)$ and at $(2,3,4)$ are the same.  Also, DougM, you seem to be ignoring the possibility of overlaps altogether.

Comment: @irchans Yes, I am aware of that... that is why I said that I was taking a short cut.  Also way I didn't take the inclusion exclusion to its exhaustion.  I haven't had the time to investigate the problem more closely.

Comment: Thanks to all that pointed out or inquired about a "flaw" that my code does not check the case where the first 4 cards dealt are the same rank such as 2,2,2,2 or K,K,K,K.  I suspect I started scanning after 6 cards have been drawn since it simplifies the code slightly and it was conceptually simpler for me since we wouldn't be searching into part of the last 3 cards dealt to find a matching triple. For example, if 20 cards have been dealt with no matching triple seen but the last 4 cards dealt are K,K,K,K, I would NOT count that as a match since I would stop scanning at card 17 for the match.

Comment: So I guess it can be said that any embedded adjacent quads will never generate a triple match cuz we are not allowing scanning for a match into the last 3 cards drawn.  You would need 6 kings for example to induce a match and since we are not using a double deck, we don't have 6 kings.  So you can basically ignore the cases where there are adjacent quads anywhere in the deck cuz those will never make a match as defined in this problem.  But yes in other types of problems that allow it, adjacent quads would count as a triple, basically matching 2/3rds of itself, but that was not my goal here.

Comment: When I first started testing this idea, I used real cards and just dealt the first 3 cards.  After that, I dealt 3 more cards and then started comparing cards (4,5,6) with (1,2,3).  If no match then I dealt card 7 and compared (5,6,7) with (1,2,3) and (2,3,4)....  It is visually simpler to do it that way and this simpler concept got carried over into my code.

Answer (score 1):

The main factor preventing this problem from having a simple closed-form answer is the possibility of $3$, $4$, or even more non-overlapping rank-triple repeats.  So we need to count carefully and correct for over-counting using the inclusion-exclusion principle.

I'm going to list *patterns* that a deck could match in order to have repeated rank-triples.  The simplest is
$$
*\;ABC*ABC\;*
$$
where $*$ indicates zero or more cards and each letter is a different rank.  There are $13\cdot12\cdot 11 = 1716$ ways to select $ABC$, and $(4\cdot 3)^3=1728$ ways to choose the suits of the two rank-triples, and $\frac{1}{2}(47\cdot 48) = 1128$ ways to place the two rank-triples within the remaining $46$ cards, so the probability is
$$
\frac{1716\cdot 1728 \cdot 1128}{52\cdot 51 \cdot 50 \cdot 49 \cdot 48 \cdot 47} \approx 0.2281873.
$$
It's also possible to have one of
$$
*\;ABA*ABA* \qquad *\;AAB*AAB* \qquad *\;BAA*BAA\;*.
$$
For each of these there are $13\cdot 12=156$ ways to select $A$ and $B$, and $4!\cdot 4 \cdot 3=288$ to choose the suits, and again $\frac{1}{2}(47\cdot 48)=1128$ ways to place the two rank-triples within the remaining $46$ cards, so the probability is
$$
\frac{3\cdot 156 \cdot 288 \cdot 1128}{52\cdot 51 \cdot 50 \cdot 49 \cdot 48 \cdot 47} \approx 0.0103721.
$$
These are the only cases with a single repeated rank-triple, and summing them gives $p_1\approx 0.238559$.  Now we need to subtract the patterns for two repeated rank-triples, add the patterns for three repeated rank-triples, subtract the patterns for four, etc.  These events are increasingly unlikely, and we have no hope of enumerating all of them by hand; but we can try to capture the largest contributions.  The most likely pattern with two repeated rank-triples is
$$
*\;ABC*ABC*DEF*DEF\;*
$$
Here there are $13\cdot12\cdot11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8=1235520$ ways to choose the ranks, $(4\cdot 3)^6=2985984$ ways to choose the suits, and $\frac{1}{8}(41\cdot 42\cdot 43 \cdot 44)=407253$ ways to place the four blocks among the remaining $40$ cards (such that $ABC$ comes before $DEF$), for a total probability of
$$
\frac{1235520\cdot 2985984 \cdot 407253}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdots 42 \cdot 41}\approx 0.0151984.
$$
The next-most dominant contributor is
$$
*\;ABCD*ABCD\;*
$$
with $13\cdot12\cdot11\cdot10=17160$ ways to select $ABCD$, and $(4\cdot 3)^4=20736$ ways to choose the suits, and $\frac{1}{2}(45\cdot 46)=1035$ ways to place the blocks, for a probability of
$$
\frac{17160\cdot 20736\cdot 1035}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot48\cdot 47\cdot46\cdot 45}\approx 0.0121376.
$$
Next is
$$
*\;ABA*CDE*ABA*CDE\;*
$$
together with its variants with $AAB$ or $BAA$ and the permutations of the four blocks.  There are $13\cdot 12\cdot 11\cdot 10\cdot 9=154440$ ways to choose $ABCDE$, and $4!\cdot(4\cdot 3)^4=497664$ ways to choose the suits, and $\frac{1}{4}(41\cdot 42\cdot 43 \cdot 44)=814506$ ways to place the four blocks among the remaining $40$ cards, so the probability here is
$$
\frac{3\cdot 154440 \cdot 497664 \cdot 814506}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdots 42 \cdot 41} \approx 0.0018998.
$$
There are more patterns for two repeated rank-triples, but these are the most common; summing them gives $p_2\approx 0.029236$.  We estimate that
$$
p = p_1 - p_2 + p_3 - p_4 + \ldots \approx 0.238559 - 0.029236 = 0.209323.
$$
This estimate is a bit high... my simulation also yields $p = 0.2032$, with the uncertainty in the last digit.  It turns out that there are a good many additional patterns to account for even for just two repeated rank-triples, each of which is unlikely, but which together account for the discrepancy.  A partial list is the following:
$$
*\;ABC*ABCDE*CDE\;* 
$$ $$
*\;ABC*ABCD*BCD\;*
$$ $$
*\;ABC*DEA*DEABC\;*
$$ $$
*\;ABC*DAB*DABC\;*
$$ $$
*\;ABCABCA\;*
$$ $$
*\;ABC*ABC*DCE*DCE\;* \ldots
$$

---

*Update*:

I've systematized my diagrammatic calculation and can report on the results.  Starting with the first pattern ($*\;ABC*ABC\;*$), at each step I generate all new patterns (modulo permutations of the blocks and left-right reversal) that can be reached by adding a single extra constraint.  I calculate the exact probability of each pattern and place new patterns in a priority queue, with the highest-probability pattern at the front of the queue.  Then iterate, at each step popping the next pattern from the queue, generating all its children, and inserting any new children back into the queue.

The procedure is complicated, but I've been able to check its results when applied to simpler cases for which exact enumeration is possible: decks with only 2, 3, or 4 ranks (and still 4 suits).  In these cases the diagrammatic calculation terminates, giving the following answers, which can be verified to be exactly correct:

- 2 ranks (4 diagrams): 24 of 70 shuffles (34.2857%) have rank-triple repeats
- 3 ranks (1786 diagrams): 14802 of 34650 shuffles (42.7186%) have rank-triple repeats
- 4 ranks (109307 diagrams): 25754256 of 63063000 shuffles (40.8389%) have rank-triple repeats

Running this algorithm on the actual problem, with $13$ ranks, yields an estimate of $20.316\%$ in just a few minutes, having considered only the top $56$ diagrams.  I'll run it overnight and see if I can arrive at a better estimate.

Comment: This is really good analysis as the letter patterns help visually identify the repeating triples.  I am happy that your simulation results match mine exactly at 20.32%.  Of course this is counting any deck with at least 1 matching triple as a match, and even if that deck has up to 7 matches (the highest  I have seen in my simulation of 100 million decks), that still counts the same as if the deck had only 1 match.  So overall, it appears that 1 out of every 5 decks will have at least one triple repeated of this type (rank and order are the same).  I will simulate 1 billion decks soon.

Comment: By the way, since I got 7 matched triples max in my simulation of 100 million decks and I doubt there will be more than 8 matched triples even when I simulate 1 billion decks, I think it is fair to say that using inclusion-exclusion principle, it will suffice to handle up to 8 matched triples but no more.  That answer should be within a tiny epsilon of the actual answer which is close enough.  Probability need not be exact in this case since we are only trying to get a feel for the likelihood, not trying to use it like at a casino to make money.  It is very interesting analysis going on here.

Comment: Regarding your comment on the uncertainty in the last digit of our matching 20.32% (0.2032), I will run a simulation of 1 billion decks and I think it is fair to say that should give us good confidence to 4 decimal places (0.2032 for example). I should have the answer by maybe Sat morning and will post it here.  I am more interested in the analysis so in the future, I can maybe try to solve similar type problems.  In fact, I may concoct another similar one to see if I can solve it and then I can write a simulation program the check it.

Comment: One "problem" I see with using math to solve a problem like this is that all of the patterns need be identified, whereas with simulation, as soon as the first match is found, we can ignore the rest of the deck and immediately shuffle a new deck.  This obviously eliminates any overcounting since we stop looking after the first match, although I can easily make the simulation so it counts all of the matching triples, even multiple per deck.

Comment: Absolutely... writing a simulation to get an approximate answer is easy (10 lines of Python code, easily verified to be correct, runs $10^6$ samples in 30 seconds), and you can run it longer to improve the approximation.  But every time you want another digit, you need to run it $100$ times longer.  So run it on a cluster, or otherwise scale up?... computer power is cheap, and human analysis is expensive and potentially error-prone, so up to a certain point simulation is the best way to go. ...

Comment: ... But if you needed, say, 12 digits of precision here, to send a man safely to the moon or something, you would want to push forward the analysis.  In that case, you might work to generate the patterns with a computer program (this can be done systematically) and compute the exact probability of each pattern, also with a program.  It's not beyond the realm of possibility that this could yield an exact solution; certainly it could be extended much further than raw simulation.

Comment: I think to generate all possible hands is somewhere on the order of 10^49 which is not possible on a computer.  However, since this type of problem has about a 20% expectancy, a sample of maybe 1 billion should be adequate to get maybe 4 or 5 accurate digits such as 0.2032.  I will be running  a simulation of 1 billion decks soon but I was first trying to speed up the algorithm since even a 10% improvement will shave a few hours of runtime for 1 billion decks.  The speed is lost in the shuffling so I am concentrating my efforts there.  The part which finds the triples is quick.

Comment: Wow, $10^6$ samples on my slug of a computer takes about 2 minutes so your simulation is about 4x the speed of mine, however we get the same answer so that is good. Unfortunately, since the pattern appears about 20% of the time and $52! / ((4!)^{13})$ is such a large number, it seems nearly impossible to generate that many decks.  For problems like this where the "hit ratio" is reasonably high, it makes more sense to just do a "Monte Carlo" simulation.  The chances of generating the same exact 52 card deck even in 1 billion simulated decks is slim to none so that answer can be trusted.

Comment: Even though I already awarded you the +100 bounty points, putting you now at 30K, I would like to hear the results of your overnight run and any other progress you make on getting this answer more exact.  The best I could reasonably do is maybe simulate 10 billion decks and calculate the percentage out to maybe 5 accurate digits after the decimal point. @mjqxxxx

Answer (score 0):

Since this problem seems very difficult to count all the patterns without overcounting, I just ran a Monte Carlo type simulation of 1 billion 1 ($10^9 + 1$) random decks, stopping at the first match in the deck and counting them up.  It took more than 24 hours to complete but I just let it run on my desktop computer while I used my laptop computer to do other things like chat...

The results I got are $20.32330$% of the decks have this property.

So I am not sure what the confidence level is from this (assuming the program and random generator are correct) but I would at least feel pretty confident about $20.323$%.

I know this solution is not mathematical, but it is still useful for checking against mathematical solutions, thus helping confirm them.

In the future what I would like to do is to store the randomly generated decks in a disk file so then later I could rerun it looking for different criteria such as a quad repeating pattern instead of a triple.  Since generating the shuffled decks is the bulk of the computer time, once I do that, I can just "quickly" read it back in (a reasonable "chunk" at a time) and check for the desired patterns.

Comment: If you ran $10^9$ and you got $N=203233000$ hits, then the error in the mean is something like $\pm \sqrt{N} / 10^9 = \pm 1.4 \times 10^{-5}$, right?  So you can say $20.323\% \pm 0.002\%$.